# VS2012, Team Explorer and My Work

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Is the [My Work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181403.aspx) ([video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Visual-Studio-2012-Premium-and-Ultimate-Overview/Visual-Studio-Ultimate-2012-How-to-multi-task-with-My-Work)) feature in VS2012's Team Explorer window seems quite handy.  However, we use Subversion.

Is this feature tightly coupled to TFS?  Is there an extension point to allow the work state (open windows, breakpoints, ...) to be persisted somewhere besides TFS?  Is there already a non-TFS implementation?

Comment: Yes, Team Explorer is tightly coupled with TFS.

Comment: @exacerbatedexpert: Other than licensing costs :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's definitely coupled to TFS - a shelveset is a feature of TFS.

The closest SVN analogy is that a shelveset is a "branch" but there is no version history on the branch - it's just a place to stick your pending changes so you can revert back to trunk for a while. Then later you go and get your pending changes back off the "shelf" and keep working on them.